# With AppleScript how can you check if spctl is enabled?

Tags: applescript, gatekeeper

I'm familiar with running the AppleScript command:

```
do shell script "sudo spctl --master-disable" with administrator privileges
```

to allow the ability in Security to select `Anywhere` but is there a way in AppleScript to detect if `spctl` is enabled or disabled?

---

### Edit:

Running the do shell with:

```
do shell script "spctl --status"
```

will throw a **Script Editor** in Script Editor:

[image]

Is there a way to get the `status` without it throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for could be:

```
try
    do shell script "spctl --status"
on error E
    E
end try
```

Returns `assessments enabled` or `assessments disabled` accordingly.

---

<sup>**System info:** *AppleScript version:* `2.7`  *System version:* `10.13.6`</sup>

Comment: Running the `do shell` at it's current state throws an *AppleScript Execution Error*.

Comment: made an edit to the question with an image.

Comment: Awe I see, I forgot you could throw it like that in a try block.